# JQuery to keep disabled button for all amounts less than 0.01, disabled

Tags: jquery

I have an amount field and some JQuery which enables/disables my submit button as shown in my code below, but the issue I have is that if the user enters 00.00 then my button becomes enabled and I don't want it to.

How can i stop it.

**JQuery**

```
if ($('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() == '' || $('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() < '0.01' || $('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() == '0.00' && e.options[e.selectedIndex].text == 'BACS')
{
     $('#FeeTotalAmounts').hide();
     $('#OneOffPayment_Submit').attr("disabled", true);
}
else
{
     $('#OneOffPayment_Submit').attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please. Odds are though that you're comparing a string instead of a number.

Comment: instead of `attr("disabled", true);` use `attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: Also, better to use `.prop("disabled", true);` with the new versions of jQuery, because it is a boolean property. Also, use `.prop("disabled", false);` or `.removeAttr("disabled");` instead of `.attr("disabled", false);`.

Comment: To everyone not readin my post correct, My disable works fine.  The issue is when i add 00.00.  When the page loads my field displays as 0.00 by default but if i add another '0' (00.00) my button then enables and i dont want it too

Comment: @PraveenKumar Read my comment. I'm not bothered about how to write my disable as it works.  the issue is when i add a leading '0'

Comment: @KalpeshSingh Read my comment. I'm not bothered about how to write my disable as it works.  the issue is when i add a leading '0'

Comment: @j08691 This is my code

Comment: @PraveenKumar, not a duplicate

Comment: @murday1983 Sorry, my bad. Reopened the question for you. Happy? `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes but if you marked my question down can you mark it back upagin please

Comment: @murday1983 Not me, but if it has been marked over 5 mins ago, kindly edit the question again, else the vote is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing your numbers as strings instead of actual numbers, which means you are basically saying `is val before 0.01 in alpha numeric order`

you should not be adding quotes around `'0.01'`

also try casting your vals

```
if ($('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() == '' || 
parseFloat($('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val()) < 0.01 || 
parseFloat($('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val()) == 0.00 && 
e.options[e.selectedIndex].text == 'BACS')
```

Comment: My disable works fine.  The issue is when i add 00.00 instead of 0.00.  When the page loads my field displays as 0.00 by default but if i add another '0' (00.00) my button enables

Comment: try casting 00.00 to a double

Comment: Also removed the `parseFloat($('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val()) == 0.00` as it wasn't needed as i was using `< 0.01` in the condition before it